# Reading lines from a file and store into variable.

Tags: c++

contents of `file.txt`

```
a
b
c

a
b
c1 x c2
d
```

a, b, c, c1, c2, d are all some values.

**My function**

```
void Menu::readFile() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("file.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline (myfile, line)) {
            cout << line << "\n";
        }

        myfile.close();
    } else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
}
```

This is just returning the contents of the file, how can I read the file and parse each line into a variable. Each line break separates the objects.

Comment: You already have the `line` in a variable. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I'd use `cerr` for error output rather than `cout`. And I'd mention the name of the file in the error message, but perhaps that's just me.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "reading lines from file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Menu::readFile() {
    string line;
    vector <string> lines;
    ifstream myfile ("file.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline (myfile, line)) {
          cout << line << "\n";
          lines.push_back(line);
        }

        myfile.close();
    } else { 
       cout << "Unable to open file"; 
    }
}
```

the variable lines will have all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

This function is not **returning** anything. It is declared and so it can not return any value. What you have is already parsing the lines one by one. Now instead of printing them on this line:

```
cout << line << "\n";
```

You should store them in some container e.g. `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a list or vector.  Here is an example using algorithms and iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> vals;

  std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::back_inserter(vals)
  );

  // Print them out, appending a newline to each word

  std::copy(
    vals.begin(),
    vals.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
  );
}
```

You can substitute any `std::istream` object initialize to the `std::istream_iterator`; in particular your `myfile` variable.  The default constructor (empty parens) constructs an end-of-stream iterator.